# Did anyone ever propose an analytic definition of zero divisors, including nilpotents, as opposed to algebraic definition?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra, zero, logarithm

I wonder, can we meaningfully define zero divisors based on analytic rather than algebraic approach?

For instance, if we extend the real numbers with divergent integrals and series, and evaluate the Maclaurin series for $\ln (x+1)$ at $x=-1$, we will obtain an expansion, equal to the Harmonic series with opposite sign: $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$.Also, if we define logarithm as $\ln x=\int_1^x \frac1x dx$, the value at $x=0$ will be divergent integral $-\int_0^1 \frac1xdx$, which can be shown via Laplace transform rule to be equal to the Harmonic series mentioned above (and also the Harmonic series is its Riemann sum). What if we define the value of $\ln 0=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k=-\int_0^1\frac1x dx$? One can rise an objection that defining logarithm of zero breaks the equality $a \ln x=\ln x^a$, but it already does not work with negative $x$.

Thus, if we denote $\ln 0=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k=\lambda$, then by some logic $\varepsilon =e^{\lambda/2}$ would be a nilpotent, such that $\varepsilon^2=0$, which is similar to the dual numbers unity. It is interesting that the regularized value of Harmonic series is $\gamma$, and thus the regularized value of $\lambda$ is $-\gamma$.

As such, I wonder whether anyone considered introduction of nilpotents and logarithm of zero via divergent series?

Comment: I remember reading in old Manin's notes on Algebraic Geometry about interpreting nilpotents as derivations in algebraic varieties.

Comment: Which equivalence relation do you put on divergent series and integrals? (Also, though I find the question interesting, I'm not sure if this is a question on the history of mathematics. Seems rather like a mathematical reference request.)

Comment: @MichaelBächtold https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075766/why-is-ln-0-ne-ln-infty

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see a general definition of when two div. integral/series are to be considered equal "extended" real numbers there.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold you can see a bigger lest of equalities here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403704/an-operation-is-defined-on-polynomials-how-do-i-generalize-it-to-other-classes and a series is considered a step-function integral like this: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)=\int_{-1/2}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\operatorname{rect}(x+k)f(k)dx$, e.g. integral of blocks centered at the steps of the series.